# How to add unknown string to file?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

For example my string is : `Hello [ ^ "World"`

I want to add it to file, is it possible? (sure `echo` will not work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information it is not clear where the problem is. This "should" work.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "input="
    set /p "input=string?"

    if not defined input exit /b

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"outputFile.txt" echo(!input!
    endlocal
```

The data is captured with delayed expansion disabled to avoid parser problems in the value assignment (in this case should not happen). Then, to avoid parser interferences in the output, delayedexpansion is activated to echo the data.